# Does anyone know a good/easy/free/open 3d modeling program?

Tags: c++, 3d, cross-platform, modeling

Does anyone know of an easy 3D modeling application like sketchup but is opensource?

I don't have time for learning blender ( guess I never will ):

and I'm a fan of having multiple small tools do their part of the job
( first cut the plank using the `saw` the nail it using the `hammer` :) ).

**Edit:**
I also might need to do some modifications to the application, for an example I want to be able to preview my GLSL shaders directly at the model. I want also be able to cut the model in half ( or as many cuts as I want to ) and have it saved in my own fileformet.

I does almost only know C++, done some hacking in other langs to.

Ask me if I'm unclear with my askings :)

**Edit2:**
I'm not a GUI tool programmer and have never done anything like a 3D editor, the most tools I've mada have been consolebased. Does anyone know a good startingpoint for a 3Dtool? ( like nehe.gamedev.net but for 3d tools instead of 3d games )

Comment: I would like one that can be used on both windows and Linux, but is it a good opensource tool I might afford porting it in any direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender is the only decent one I know, why not taking a look in Youtube/Vimeo on some tutorials? There are plenty and it's quite fast to scrap with Video tutorials.

Comment: I've sadly quite much given up on my 3D-projects, I'm still going to make a 3D-game some day. But I guess that all the models will be the result of some mathematical function like 4D-Perlin noise and `sphere(x,y,z,r)+cube(…)`. Still, there might be some hope for Blender. It looks like they revamps their UI

Comment: @Frank: I re-tried (out of curiosity, of course, I'm no 3D artist) Blender recently, and the changes in the UI are much more than a revamp actually. The UI now is much more "consistent" and usable.

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco: Hehe, I'm not an 3D artist, nor digital artist myself. I can do wonders with pencil and paper, but on computers, I can only express myself with algorithms xD -- I will have to try using blender again, some day. Right now, I'm doing a Web Framework/CLI Utility/Awesome using node.js ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it helps, but you might look at Wings 3D. Also, Blender is not that strange once you spend an hour working with it :-)

Comment: Well, haven't tested out Wings 3d as much. I might have been unclear, I might need to edit stuff and donät know Erlang. I does almost only know C++ ( and x86 16bit assembler )

Answer (score 2):

[Anim8or](http://www.anim8or.com/) is not open source and is windows only, but is **really** easy to use, and has very good tutorials.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that one :) It was the first one I've ever tried.

It's about the cons, not so fast ( thinking in modeling, otherwise it's fast), not open source :/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd say skip all the open source apps, go download either 3ds Max Learning edition or Maya Learning Edition, take a few years off. Just jump into the deepest end you can, and if you stick at it long and hard enough; you might just become a 3d artist. There is NO shortcut, forget the 'easy' stuff. Just my 0.2 Cent

Comment: Oh, I personally hates all those buttons and other controllers intruding on my workspace. I love the sketching idea of Google Sketchup, it does not take long time at all to create some decent models - even for the beginner.

I don't like the ruby that Sketchup uses. If it were python, I would say thats okay.

Answer (score 1):

I rememebered that Truespace 3 used to be available for free. - Whilst checking out Caligari's site to check if this was still true....I notice that 7.6 is available for free.

Theres a letter from the founder of Caligari - explaining the reason for this - and advising people to download and backup the installers. Hopefully if the 'slump' turns around Microsoft will reinvest and make this product available again.

But for now 7.6 + SDK + video + tutorials are ALL FREE

http://www.caligari.com/

Answer (score 1):

THere is no such thing as easy 3d so get that notion out of your head right now. You are gonna have to sit down and learn one platform or another at some time, why not now? Nothing is for free in the end but hard work pays off .

I started at zero two months ago and I'm building scenes now (with premade models) and animating now.

If you don't have the time don't bother because you will just get frustrated with your results.

TO use your analogy, if you don't know how to hold the hammer how are you gonna nail?

Comment: Ever heard of Anim8or, Google Sketchup, Sculpting tools (Like ZBrush)?

Answer (score 0):

[Blender's](http://www.blender.org/) OK, if a little quirky but does have a nice plugin architecture and a few nice utilities like mesh unwrap ( saves hours of UVing time ).
I'd highly recommend the [SoftImage Mod Tool](http://www.softimage.com/products/modtool/) - it's basically the full version of SoftImage with a minor few restrictions on stuff like max mesh count. It also has nice XNA integration too.

Comment: [Limitations of Autodesk Softimage Mod Tool 7.5](http://www.softimage.com/products/modtool/inside.aspx):
Non-Commercial End User License Agreement

Even if I don't earn money for all of my projects, food isn't free :)

Comment: If you're going to use this commercially then I'd suggest splashing the cash on a proper paid for tool.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [AC3D](http://www.inivis.com/) but it's not free ($80) though pretty affordable I think. There is an plugin API to do extra stuff too.